# Number of zeros inside an annulus using Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Given the function:
$$
f(z)=z^9 +10z^2+1
$$
The number of zeros in $1 \leq |z| \leq 2$ is found by applying Rouche's theorem:
$$
Z(f) = (Z(f) \text{ in }|z| \leq 2) - (Z(f) \text{ in }|z| \leq 1)
$$
On $|z|=1, |z^9| < |10z^2+1| \rightarrow Z(f) = 9$ in $|z| \leq 1$

On $|z|=2, |z^9| > |10z^2+1| \rightarrow Z(f) = 2$ in $|z| \leq 2$

Thus, $Z(f) = 9-2 = 7$ on $1 \leq |z| \leq 2$

**My question is:** When counting the number of zeros of $z^9$ inside $|z| \leq 2$, how do we know that all the 9 zeros of $z^9$ are inside the disk $|z| \leq 2?$

Comment: The zeros of $z^9$ are $0$ with multiplicity $9$, and $|0|=0\leq 2$.  Also, your question appears to get the disks of radius $1$ and $2$ mixed up (your fifth line starts with $|z|=1$, and concludes something about $|z|\leq 2$).

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to post an answer?